# Working with DelegateCommand's CanExecute action

Tags: wpf, mvvm, prism, delegatecommand

I've a ViewModel class like this in a Prism / WPF project.

```cs
public class ContentViewModel : ViewModelBase, IContentViewModel
{
    public ContentViewModel(IPersonService personService)
    {
        Person = personService.GetPerson();
        SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save, CanSave);
    }

    public Person Person { get; set; }

    public DelegateCommand SaveCommand { get; set; }

    private void Save()
    {
        // Save actions here...
    }

    private bool CanSave()
    {
        return Person.Error == null;
    }
}
```

The person type used in the above ViewModel is defined as follows:

```cs
public class Person : INotifyPropertyChanged, IDataErrorInfo
{
    private string _firstName;
    public string FirstName
    {
        get { return _firstName; }
        set
        {
            _firstName = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");
        }
    }

    // other properties are implemented in the same way as above...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }

    private string _error;
    public string Error
    {
        get
        {
            return _error;
        }
    }

    public string this[string columnName]
    {
        get
        {
            _error = null;
            switch (columnName)
            {
                // logic here to validate columns...
            }
            return _error;
        }
    }
}
```

An instance of ContentViewModel is set as DataContext of a View. Inside the View I've used binding to Person as follows:

```
<TextBox Text="{Binding Person.FirstName, ValidatesOnDataErrors=True}" />
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

When I make changes to TextBox which is binded to Person's properties like FirstName and click Save I could see the changes in ViewModel command handler. But if any of these properties fail in validation CanSave is never executed and button never gets disabled.

How do I disable a button based on DelegateCommand's CanExecute action handler in the above scenario?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this with all the properties that can change error:

```
 public string FirstName
{
    get { return _firstName; }
    set
    {
        _firstName = value;
        OnPropertyChanged("FirstName");

        OnPropertyChanged("Error");
    }
}
```

Alternatively

```
        switch (columnName)
        {
            // logic here to validate columns...

            OnPropertyChanged("Error");
        }
```

The problem you are having is that the OnPropertyChanged is not being called when the error changes.

The next step is to subscribe to the person's propertychanged event when its created, and create a handler that checks for the propertychanged and then changes the boolean variable that the command uses.

```
 public ContentViewModel(IPersonService personService)
{
    Person = personService.GetPerson();
    Person.PropertyChanged+= PersonPropertyChangedHandler;
    SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save, personHasError);
}

bool personHasError = false;
void PersonPropertyChangedHandler(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.PropertyName == "Error")
    {
        if(Person.Error == null)
           personHasError = true;
        else
           personHasError = false;
    } 
}
```

Hope this works. I built this by hand and didn't check it so let me know if its buggy or whatever and ill correct it

Comment: The problem you are having is that the OnPropertyChanged is not being called when the error changes. +1

Answer (score 4):

In the constructor of ContentViewModel add this line

```
public ContentViewModel(IPersonService personService)
{
    //GetPerson
    Person.PropertyChanged +=person_PropertyChanged;
}
```

And write an method to handle that event in which you call either CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested() or SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()

```
private void person_PropertyChanged(object sender, EventArgs args)
{
   CommandManager.InvalidateRequerySuggested();
   //SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()
}
```

Hope this works. :-)

Comment: Issue is that when you update TextBox binding to Person.FirstName Person is never treated as changed and its PropertyChanged event won't be fired.

Comment: In the setter of the FirstName you are raising a PropertyChanged event with 'FirstName' as argument right? So when the FirstName changes, this gets raised. And in person_PropertyChanged you can check if the argument string is 'FirstName'and do things accordingly

Comment: I've logic in person class to validate its columns - see the indexer in Person class which is implementing IDataErrorInfo. What will be the best way to implement validation without duplicating logic in ViewModel as well? Your suggestion works when I'm ready to implement some kind of validation in ViewModel - in such case IDataErrorInfo is useless.

Comment: See if this solves you are problem: http://www.arrangeactassert.com/using-idataerrorinfo-for-validation-in-mvvm-with-silverlight-and-wpf/

Answer (score 1):

In the nutshell - you should call `yourDelegateCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` when you think that your `CanExecute()` return value can be changed.

In your example, you should notify through `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface that your `Person.Error` property is changed, subscribes to `Person.PropertyChanged` event in your `ContentViewModel` class and call `SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged()` each time when your `Person.Error` is changed. Please be careful - in your scenario `Person.Error` isn't recalculated automatically when, for example, `Person.FirstName` is changed - you should do this manually.

**UPDATED:**

```
public class ContentViewModel : ViewModelBase, IContentViewModel
{
    public ContentViewModel(IPersonService personService)
    {
        Person = personService.GetPerson();
        Person.PropertyChanged += Person_PropertyChanged;
        SaveCommand = new DelegateCommand(Save, CanSave);
    }

    private void PersonPropertyChangedHandler(object sender, PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
    }

    private void Save()
    {
        // Save actions here...
    }

    private bool CanSave()
    {
        return IsErrorPresented(Person);
    }

    private bool IsErrorPresented(object o)
    {
        if (!(o is IDataErrorInfo))
            return false;

        var propNames = o.GetType()
            .GetProperties(BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance)
            .Select(p => p.Name);

        var o2 = (o as IDataErrorInfo);

        var errors = propNames.Select(p => o2[p])
            .Where(p => !String.IsNullOrEmpty(p))
            .ToList();

        ValidationSummary.ErrorMessages = errors;

        return errors.Count > 0;
    }
}

<TextBox Text="{Binding Person.FirstName, 
                        UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged, 
                        ValidatesOnDataErrors=True, 
                        ValidatesOnExceptions=True, 
                        NotifyOnValidationError=True}" />
<Button Content="Save" Command="{Binding SaveCommand}" />
```

If you will also specify `PropertyChanged` as `UpdateSourceTrigger`, your save button will be updated during your typing..

Comment: You mean something like this         private Person _person;
        public Person Person
        {
            get
            {
                return _person;
            }
            set
            {
                _person = value;
                if (_person.Error != null)
                    SaveCommand.RaiseCanExecuteChanged();
                OnPropertyChanged("Person");
            }
        } I dont get any notification in People when it's child change. I think that is the problem here.